ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed "pip install solana"
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
python-telegram-bot 21.0.1 requires httpx~=0.27, but you have httpx 0.23.3 which is incompatible.
Tried installing "pip install --user solana"

It's good style on SO when asking a question to ... actually ask a question.
